# Regarding Crime in Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have a question regarding the crime system in Skyrim.

As you can see, I'm trying to finish Skyrim with no crimes as possible with the exception of lock-picking as there are some areas in the game that requires me to pick locks to enter or chests in dungeons that require me to pick them before obtaining the contents within. Right now, I am about 60% into the game with 0 crimes on everything, excluding lock-picking. I am fairly proud of this accomplishment and there are even some missions where I was required to commit a crime but managed to find a workaround so that I could do it without committing any crime. (Such as assassinating a high value target using frenzy).

However, there are some missions/quests that require me to commit certain crimes that I can't find a workaround. One particular quest in mind is where you sneak into Black-Briar Lodge to STEAL Frost's papers and then STEAL Frost and deliver it to someone. Most of the time, when I'm confronted with a quest that requires me to steal, I often use my followers to do my dirty work for me as not to count to my stealing record. Stealing the papers won't be a problem. The problem is breaking and entering. You see, to obtain Frost's papers, I need to break inside Black-Briar Lodge to obtain it. I tried everything from entering during daylight and using magic mods to magically "unlock" a door for me. However, once I'm inside, it automatically counts as trespassing. I tried asking my follower to go inside but he won't obey me.

My question is: Is there a way to bypass a breaking and entering situation such as this one? I can't really befriend Maven Black-Briar since there is no way to accomplish that. I'm stuck with this mission so far. Do you guys have any suggestions or workarounds to this particular situation? Another mission that also falls under this category is Ondolemar's request to break into a Nord Bard's house and steal an Amulet of Talos. The stealing part is easy enough to bypass, but I can't seem to find a way to bypass trespassing.

Comment: I have no idea if this will change anything but you can actually tell Maven that you are doing this and I believe she says to go along with it. That might remove it from being a crime but I have never checked... At the end of the day you might want to give up on trespassing the same as you did lock picking though.

Comment: I actually did the optional quest of telling Maven Black-Briar regarding Sibbi's plan. However it did not change anything and everything inside Black-Briar Lodge is considered stealing and entering it will count as trespassing. I guess even telling Maven about Sibbi's plan does not affect your relationship with her.

Comment: Since there are so many quests in Skyrim, how about not doing this one? Since your character won't do crime then it's perfectly normal for him/her to deny it.

Comment: Are you on pc? If so I have an idea that might help you out.

Comment: @Dragonrage: I'm all ears, mate. Let's hear it.

Comment: You can try using the console command "setrelationshiprank # 3" where # is maven's id. If rank 3 doesn't work try 4. I don't know if it will work, but it's worth a try

Comment: I'm a little confused as to why you're even pursuing these quests if you don't want to commit crimes. These quests are about committing crimes.

Comment: You could have your companion murder said person. That way no one would technically own that place anymore and it wouldn't be trespassing.

Comment: Followers follow your orders, in the eyes of the law that makes you guilty!

Comment: @Dragonrage: I was hoping of not using the console to be honest because I'm also aware of the command that alters your relationship with any NPC. However, it seems that I've really hit the dead end and there's no way around this. I might have to commit a crime on this one.

Answer (score 6):

If you are attempting a **"lawful good"** type play through like I think you are, you usually can't do these kinds of missions, unfortunately. They sound like Thieve's Guild, Dark Brotherhood, or from some sketchy dude in Markarth, and these kinds of missions would inherently go against a lawful good style. The only other way to accomplish this would *literally* be hacking, but that would also go against a lawful good style.

If you really want to "finish" Skyrim, as in completing *all* the quests and not just the main story quest, then you will need to commit some crimes (or hack, but that breaks immersion). Otherwise you are out of luck.